# Mostra valores de distintas tablas de bd MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Alguna linea que tenga que agregar al siguiente código. Asi comi esta estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado. En un caso donde la base de datos tiene una sola tabla y del mismo nombre.

Pero como en la misma pagina quiero hacer varias consultas, opte por usar distintas tablas de una misma base de datos.

Entonces tengo que agregar algo al a este codigo

la base actual es baseuno

quiero usar otra base ,seria  de nombre basedos y  con tablas de nombres: tablauno, tablados, tablatres, etc , La consulta es si agregando alguna línea al siguiente codigo seria suficiente para resolverlo.

```
<?php 
            $query = "select * from baseuno";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['entidad'];
                $email = $row['localidad'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><strong>".$name."<strong></td>";
                echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
                echo "<td><button data-id='".$id."' class='userinfo'>Info</button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
```

Muchas gracias Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué al inicio de tu pregunta existe una especie de conversación en inglés?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, no sé tampoco a qué le llamas "base" y también a qué quieres llegar con todo esto.

Comment: Hola, me refiero base.sql  que esta en el  servidor .

Comment: De nombre entidades.sql, con una tabla con todas las entidades de todas las localidades.  Ahora en vez de tener una sola tabla tiene una distinta por localidad.   Necesito  que la consulta se realice solo en una localidad. En la web se muestra una tabla de dos columnas, el nombre y la localidad (al campo $email le cambie para que muestre la localidad). Pero quiero que sea toda la lista de una localidad y por eso hice varias tablas una por localidad, en la misma entidades.sql . Pensé que habría que modificar $query = "select * from entidades";

Comment: Desde que leo cosas como *tablaUno, tablaDos, tablaTres, tablaMil*, pienso que hay un error de diseño. ¿Podrías explicar mejor el contexto para ayudarte en una solución más óptima? ¿Por qué tantas tablas que parecen ser indénticas están diferenciadas? ¿No será ese el principal problema que habrá que resolver tarde o temprano?

Comment: Hola. Hice una base de datos en MySql subiendo importando un archivo .sql con varios CREATE TABLE a una base de datos previamente creada de nombre entidades. CREATE TABLE zonanorte CREATE TABLE zonasur  y tres mas y cada uno con sus respectivos datos.Entonces quedó estructurada con el nombre entidades contenienso estas cinco tablas . El diseño actual es directamente con el nombre entidades ya que solamente contine una lista todas juntas .Ahora, conteniendo cinco que modificacion tendria que hacer en el codigo q se ve. Tendré que especificar entidades y zonasur , ambas en algun lado, ?gracias